Why tailwind css doesn't work on my sveltekit project with vite?
I have a svelte kit project that has installed tailwind css, but the tailwind css doesn't work.
The tailwind css classes doesn't affect the text i have, here my code in ./src/routes/+page.svelte:
<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>

The output should show a text with 30px font size, bold and have line under the text, but it shows this:
Output in localhost
Project structre
Here is my tailwind css config, note that the project is with typescript:
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss';

export default {
    content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{svelte,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    theme: {
        extend: {}
    },
    plugins: []
} satisfies Config;


postcss.config.js:


export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}



Note
If you want the code of a file, say in the comments

It seems you may not have integrated Tailwind properly. Consider following the guide on the Tailwind website.

Share your app.css and postcss.config.js

@vit Ok, i add it but i dont have app.css because i maked the app with vite js. i have the postcss.config.js so i add it

I Founded that if you create +layout.svelte file and write this code:


<script>
 // After installing the tailwind css
 import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
</script>

<!-- Put anything from the +page.svelte file here  -->
<slot />


Its import the tailwind css file that saved all classes to use it like a css file
